# tuple index out of range ERROR using 'where' sql in python Method

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm doing a select with 'where' in sql db,  but I always get a tuple index out of range ERROR.

Can someone help me with this?

This is my method:

```
def validate_if_data_exist(self, id_user: int, id_parameter: int, message: str) -\> None:

        try:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                query = """SELECT id_user,id_parameter,l.created_at, a.created_at, l.message  
                    FROM alerts_users as a , alerts as l
                    WHERE id_user=%s AND a.created_at = '%2022-04-01%' AND l.id_parameter = %s AND    l.message  = 'vencer'
                    AND l.created_at = '%2022-04-01%' 
                    GROUP by l.id_parameter, id_user,l.created_at,a.created_at,l.message;"""
              
                cursor.execute(query,(id_user,id_parameter))
                periodicities = cursor.fetchall()
    
                print(periodicities)
```

Comment: What is `%2022-04-01%` supposed to be doing? Pretty sure it is the cause of your error, `psycopg2` is taking it as a placeholder and runs out of parameters in the tuple: `(id_user,id_parameter)`. If just want to pass a date string then do `a.created_at = '2022-04-01'`

Comment: Yes,  thank you.  That was the problem